# Nightwatch Cannot Find/Click on Dropdown Option

Tags: css, nightwatch.js

I'm a backpacker and a programmer, trying to use the second skill to find openings in a full campsite. Rather than crawling fro scratch, I'm using the end-to-end testing framework nightwatch.js to navigate for me.

I've hit a roadblock, because nightwatch is having difficulty finding a specific element using css selectors.

#### Here are the elements and page:

[image: Permit type]

#### Here is my test code:

[image: Test code]

#### Previous Attempts

My test code **will** click on the selection box with `#permitTypeId`. It will see that `#permitTypeId option` is visible. It will **not** see or click on any of the options when more specific values are specified. The five `.click()`'s are all css selectors I've already tried. None of the options are set to `display:hidden` or `display:none`. I have also tried all of the above without the `.waitForElementToBeVisible()` just in-case the waiting causes the dropdown to hide.

I've successfully clicked options from different dropdown menus on this website without any problem. Just this one is causing a headache.

The tests are running with the most current Selenium server and Firefox on Mac Yosemite.

#### tl;dr

Nightwatch.js/Selenium won't click on something from a dropdown menu.

Comment: Try `.trigger('click')` instead

Comment: What is the syntax for specifying which element to trigger the click event on?

Comment: $('element').trigger('click');

Comment: Ahh, didn't know nightwatch had a different syntax than jquery. Deleted my answer. Maybe the `setValue` command would work for a select element, too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The Path...

Cory got me thinking about jQuery and native DOM manipulation. Tried going that route and was successful selecting the correct option using Selenium's `.execute()` function:

```
.execute('document.getElementById("permitTypeId").options[1].selected=true')
```

However, it was not triggering the `onchange` event.

Saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795354/selenium-webdriver-sendkeys-does-not-trigger-onchange-event-in-ie9-0) which made me start thinking about using key-strokes and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907512/firing-change-events-in-selenium-and-iex) which suggested using arrow-keys to navigate down a `<select>` element to the option, then hitting enter.

#### ...to the Solution

```
.click('select[id=permitTypeId]')
.keys(['\uE015', '\uE006'])
```

I've found that this is an issue with Firefox. Chrome and PhantomJS operate well clicking `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to click like this way

```
browser.click('select[id="permitTypeId"] option[value="1451140610"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

Additionally I was able to add a .click event for the specific option once I did a .click for the select. see my example below:

```
.click('select[name="timezone"]') 
.pause(1000)
.click('option[value="America/Chicago"]') //selects the option but doesn't click
.pause(5000)
.keys(['\uE006']) //hits the enter key.
```

Answer (score 2):

another solution:

```
  .click('select[id="permitTypeId"]')
  .waitForElementVisible("option[value='1451140610']")
  .click("option[value='1451140610']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way is to use `.setValue('@element', 'value of option')`